# Typescript Extend String interface Runtime Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am extending the typescript String interface in my Angular app. I have added a method translate() which is accessible throughout my app. **I do not get any compile errors.**

However, I get a runtime error:

> "TypeError: "Translate this string".translate is not a function"

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

---

Here are the screenshots of my implementation:

**Declaration:**

[image]

**Implementation**

[image]

**Calling:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see any [extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) here, just an interface called `String`.

Comment: @crashmstr I dont need the extends here since I am implementing a new method in the existing typescript String interface and going to use it globally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem. Here is an update on how to solve this issue:

---

> **1.** Create a file `global.d.ts` and add the interface extension definitions there.

```
export { };
declare global
{
    interface String
    {
        /**
         * Translates the given string according to the culture provided.
         * @param cultureName The culture name of the translation target.
         * @returns The translated string.
         */
        translate(cultureName: string): string;
    }
}
```

> **2.** Create another file with the interface extension methods definition. In my case I named it `string.extensions.ts`

```
/**
 * Translates the given string according to the culture provided.
 * @param cultureName The culture name of the translation target.
 * @returns The translated string.
 */    
String.prototype.translate = function(cultureName: string): string
{
    const inputValue = this;

    // Do the translation here
    const translatedValue = 'Willkommen bei meiner App'; // Only for example

    return translatedValue ;
};
```

> **3.** In your app boot file, in my case its `main.ts`, add a reference to the `global.d.ts` and the file containing your extension methods
>   definitions.

```
/// <reference path="app/core/extensions/global.d.ts" />
//...
import './app/core/extensions/string.extensions';
```

You just need to import this file once in your project (`main.ts`) and then you can use it anywhere in the code.

> **4.** Example use in my AppComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        Original Value: <h3>{{ originalValue }}</h3>
        Translated Value: <h3>{{ translatedValue }}</h3> 
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    private originalValue:string;
    private translatedValue:string;

    constructor() {          
        this.originalValue = 'Welcome to my App';
        this.translatedValue = 'Welcome to my App'.translate('de-DE'); 
    }      
}
```

---

That's all you need to do to solve this annoying problem.

Here is a link to working plunker: [**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YsTw3meNQtuQqtdGHjrC?p=preview)

Comment: not working with angular 12  (2021)

Comment: I can confirm it's working with Angular 12.2.0

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

**Declare an interface**

```
interface String {
    translate():string
}
```

**Usage**

```
String.prototype.translate = function(){
     return "boink"
}

let str : string = "test";
let a : string = str.translate();
console.log(a);   // logs "boink"
```

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to work in Angular. When I try the exact same code in a non-Angular project it works!

Comment: yup, see my own answer to this post to make it work in angular.

Comment: Wow, nice! Such a hassle to figure this stuff out... the typescript docs are really inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your declaration is in a separated files. It still uses the base declaration. It is not reachable to the code. Try use the direct import from the file or this one.

```
///<reference path="test.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: Yes, my declaration is in a separate file. I have included the reference path but that didn't help.

Comment: Why do not you use pipes for this business case? | translate ?

Comment: I have added the pipe already. I also want to call the pipe transform inside my translate function, as a new String extension function "translate". I dont want to import my TranslationService everywhere in the code.

Comment: You have published the plunk. But It does not disclose the typescript behavior. I guess you simply did not defined the method properly. This is JavaScript error - "TypeError: "Translate this string".translate is not a function" So this method has not been attached yet before you call it.